# Settings the background of a CanvasView in layout xml not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have a CanvasView that I found open source online. See below for link.

```
  <com.brettrosen.atls.canvas.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/margin_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/loose_leaf"/>
```

I have an image called `loose_leaf.png` in my drawable folder. However, when I set that image as the background for my CanvasView, it does not take effect. Does this have something to do with the CanvasView functionality (as in it doesn't support it) or am I doing something wrong? Is there something I could add to make this work?

[CanvasView github](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView)